# Airflow: DAG status is success even when no task ran

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

In its 2 out of 10 runs, the DAG status automatically sets to succes even when no tasks inside of it ran. Following is the DAG args which was passed and its tree view.

```
args = {
    'owner': 'xyz',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catchup': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019, 7, 8),
    'email': ['a@b.c'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'provide_context': True,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2)
}
```

[image]

And I am passing DAG as a context like this:

```
with DAG(PARENT_DAG_NAME, default_args=args, schedule_interval='30 * * * *') as main_dag:
    task1 = DummyOperator(
    task_id='Raw_Data_Ingestion_Started',
    )
    task2 = DummyOperator(
    task_id='Raw_Data_Ingestion_Completed',
    )

    task1 >> task2
```

Any idea what could be the issue? Is it something I need to change in the config file? And this behaviour is not periodic.

Comment: I am having the same problem. The annoying bit is that a I have another dag which has some tasks that make some computations with pyspark, and that dag runs fine.

Comment: I had the same issue, and it was fixed after I deleted the existing DAG (from UI) and changing the name of the DAG to a different one. I changed from "_v1" to "_v2"

Answer (score -3):

According to the official [airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/operators/dummy_operator/index.html?highlight=dummyoperator) on DummyOperator:

> Operator that does literally nothing. It can be used to group tasks in a DAG.

Comment: even if they are dummy operators they should still run and change color to green.